# Is there a point/advantage to using Protractor and a Selenium framework (like Serenity)

Tags: angular, selenium, protractor

For an Angular8 project, is there any need to have booth protractor tests and serenity tests? (Serenity is a selenium framework for test automation)

Seems like they both do the same thing and serve the same purpose, so you would just be duplicating tests in that case. Is this the case?

Answer (score 1):

As per the serenity documentation states : https://github.com/jan-molak/serenity-js

> Serenity/JS is a next generation acceptance testing library, expanding the capabilities of Angular Protractor

It seems to be the case then.

---

On a side note, nrwl/nx promotes the usage of cypress, which seems to be reliable and also more powerful than protractor : https://www.cypress.io/

So if you haven't started using protractor, using cypress might be a cool idea as well.

Comment: Cypress is not open source. It comes with price. Not all organizations are interested in investing into automation tools. Protractor is free.

Comment: Cypress is Open Source ! https://www.cypress.io/pricing : The test runner is always free to have and use. Only the online solution requires payment which is not mandatory at all.

Comment: Oh ok. I had a wrong notion that its not open source. Thanks for the info. I will consider it for my search of automation tools.